# AngularJS directive won't detect controller scope that binds variables using "this"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, scope, directive

I have the following angularJS controller and directive:

```
angular.module('twitterApp', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl)
    .directive('enter', EnterFunc);

function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.loadMoreTweets = function() {
        alert('loading more tweets!');
    }
}

function EnterFunc() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function() {
            scope.loadMoreTweets();
        });
    }
}
```

And the following HTML

```
  <body ng-app="twitterApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <div enter>
        Roll over to load more tweets
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Now, this works perfectly, since all I'm doing is accessing the controller's scope from a directive. However, I'm trying to adapt my controller to bind variables to the "this" scope so I can use the "controller as" syntax on the html to make it easier to read, however, when I change my controller function to the following:

```
function AppCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.loadMoreTweets = function() {
        alert('loading more tweets!');
    }
}
```

My example stops working and upon clicking on the directive I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: scope.loadMoreTweets is not a function
```

Can someone explain how to get this directive to work without going back to binding to $scope? Here is the Plunkr for the not/working "Controller As" version: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/PyIA4HVOMLn0KNJ5V2bc?p=info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it for now, but posting my solution in case other people stumble upon this. To fix this, instead of using "scope.loadMoreTweets()" on my directive, I used "scope.ctrl.loadMoreTweets()". Even tough this works, I'm not very happy that there isn't a way to access the parent scope without the ".ctrl" since ".$parent" didn't work either. If someone has a better solution please let me know. There should be more documentation on using directives with Controller's Controller As syntax.

Comment: Please understand that the controllerAs syntax is NOT a different scope. All it does is makes the controller available on the scope under a specific variable name. A more Angular way to do what you want would be to move the logic in your controller into a Service and inject that service into the directive.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to pass a reference to which controller's scope you want to pass to the directive. Then you can call the method on the reference. See if this works for you

Directive:

```
function EnterFunc() {
  return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            controller: '='
        },
        link: link
    }
   function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        //scope.$apply(attrs.action);
        scope.controller.loadMoreTweets();
      });
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="twitterApp">
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
  <div enter controller="ctrl">
    Roll over to load more tweets
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the same as my solution, but with the controller alias moved to the html. Also, the scope: { controller:  '='} didn't help with anything.

Comment: Yes it is, the scope:{ =} lets you pass references to object from the parent to the directive. So another way of how you did it